# can someone explain the use of で particle in this sentence: こんなに単純で当たり前なこと

Tags: translation, meaning, particles, particle-で

i'm getting confused with the で particle in this sentence. 
This line belongs to Keno.

The complete line is: こんなに単純で当たり前なことが 本当は、一番見失いがちだからね.

Comment: Do you have anything to show an attempt at reconciling it's meaning or have you tried to translate it?

Comment: 'It's these natural and obvious things that get lost first'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「こんなに単純{たんじゅん}**で**当{あ}たり前{まえ}**な**ことが 本当{ほんとう}は、一番{いちばん}見失{みうしな}いがちだからね。」

First, notice (if you have not) that ***two*** na-adjectives are used to modify 「こと」 in this sentence -- 「単純な」 and 「当たり前な」 to use their dictionary forms.

To connect multiple adjectives or verbs in one clause, all except the last one ***must*** be conjugated into their 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form").  Thus it is ***incorrect*** to say:

> 「単純**な**当たり前**な**こと」 using 「な」 twice

You need to turn the first adjective 「単純**な**」 into its 連用形.  Its 連用形 is 「単純**で**」.  Voilà, that is the answer.  The ***correct*** phrase is:

> 「単純**で**当たり前**な**こと」

Finally, here is how na-adjective 「単純な」 conjugates.

未然形{みぜんけい}　(imperfective form): 単純**だろ**（う）

連用形{れんようけい}　(continuative form): 単純**だっ**（た）、単純**で**（ある/ない） and 単純**に**

終止形{しゅうしけい} (predicative form): 単純**だ**

連体形{れんたいけい}  (attributive form): 単純**な**

仮定形{かていけい}  (hypothetical form): 単純**なら**

(Unlike with verbs, there is no 命令形{めいれいけい} (imperative form) for adjectives.)

So, the sentence means:

> "Things that are this simple and ordinary are actually the things that we most tend to lose sight of."

It was on purpose that I have written a much longer answer than I should have because I keep seeing questions regarding adjective and verb conjugations asked when the questioners themselves do not even seem to be aware that they are conjugation questions.