# Confusion about meaning due to spacing and で particle

Tags: particle-で

I'm playing a game and came across the following:

> 彼女が自然と人を惹きつけるのは
> きっと．．．．．．
>
> あなたの　誠実で大きな背中を見て
> 育ったからなのでしょう。

For some reason I cannot understand the meaning of the second chunk due to the space after 「あなたの」 and the で particle in 「誠実で大きな背中」

I want to read it as

> She attracts people naturally
> Certainly......
>
> Due to your... sincerity she looks at your big back and
> it's probably because she has grown up

Generally I have treated spaces like this as a slight pause. As if the person it trying find the words to say. But in this case I'm very unsure as the second sentence seems very wrong

So what is actually trying to be conveyed here or am I right?

Context:

There was a man who was known to be very honest and sincere. Him and his daughter get into an argument one day. She ends up saying "I wish you were big and cool! I hate you!". Unfortunately, soon after the man immediately dies from an accident. He then becomes a ghost that takes a gigantic form

After defeating him in battle and before going to heaven, your party has a conversation with him. His daughter is mentioned by one of your teammates. The teammate says his daughter has many friends and lives her days in good health. Then the teammate says the above

Comment: [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57191/can-someone-explain-the-use-of-%e3%81%a7-particle-in-this-sentence-%e3%81%93%e3%82%93%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ab%e5%8d%98%e7%b4%94%e3%81%a7%e5%bd%93%e3%81%9f%e3%82%8a%e5%89%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8/57194#57194) might help with で.

Comment: As a native Japanese speaker, I would say there is not much if any implied meaning in the space in question.  The possible intention might be some kind of hesitation or pause. The whole sentence roughly means: "She attracts people naturally since she has grown up while following in your footsteps in developing sincerity and bigheartedness.

Comment: @user48754 you could post that comment as an answer so that OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「背中を見て...」is an expression, and while it means *look at one's back* literally, it's used to mean *by someone's example* metaphorically.

I'm assuming it has something to do with students who learn their master's techniques by peeking over their shoulder, though I can't find any sources for that claim. However, the Japanese Thesaurus clarifies [a similar expression](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E7%88%B6%E3%81%AE%E8%83%8C%E4%B8%AD%E3%82%92%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%A6%E8%82%B2%E3%81%A4):

> **「父の背中を見て育つ」**
>
> 子供が父親の物事に取り組む姿勢を見て、そこから学び大きくなること

All in all, I believe that passage boils down to meaning something along the lines of:

> I'm sure she naturally attracts people, because she grew up to be sincere and great, just like you.

Albeit a bit more literary.

The particle で is, as Shurim said in the comments, a way to apply multiple adjectives to a single noun.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it has everything summarized / condensed into one post. The weblio link definitely helped clear things up too!

Answer (score 1):

あなたの, 誠実な and 大きな all modify 背中. The author may have wanted to prevent あなたの誠実 from being read as “your sincerity” with that space. It’s not a common practice at all. And 誠実な背中 is not a very common combination. This may have added to the confusion.